# How to allow in apex controller

Tags: apex

I need to use all the wild cards and special characters in soql query.
string searchkeyword = search +'%'
it does not allowing *somevalues.
i want * results also.how to achieve it?
now i am using query like select id,name from obj like searchkeyword.

Comment: Can you clarify by adding an example of a search string, some values that are matching candidates, and the desired match results? I'm not clear what you want.

Comment: String searchKey = '%' +searchKeyWord+'%';                                                                                                    List <object> lstOfobj = [select f1,f2 from object
                                   where (f1 LIKE: searchKey ) limit 10];                                                   i am setting searchkey values from lightning input field.Now when i am testing i am not getting the results for *a,*a*, i want this * based results also.How to get them,do i need to modify my query?

Comment: You'll want to use SOSL, not SOQL. It supports searches similar to the search box in Salesforce's default UI.

Comment: Are you using `*` as a wild card or trying to search for a literal asterisk?

Comment: using * as wild card

Comment: You're not going to get `*a` in a SOQL query very easily. That is going to be a "non-selective" query that will require every field to be searched. You're asking the engine to search every string for an 'a' character, then return the 'a' plus everything that's in front of it. That's going to be a very "expensive" query to run if you look at it in the query optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk character `*` is not a wild card for the purposes of SOQL, [which uses the `%` character with the `LIKE` comparison operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) to perform wildcarded searches:

> The LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL is similar to the LIKE operator in SQL; it provides a mechanism for matching partial text strings and includes support for wildcards.
>
> - The % and _ wildcards are supported for the LIKE operator.
> - The % wildcard matches zero or more characters.
> - The _ wildcard matches exactly one character.

You can perform a wild card-based search in SOQL by using `%`, which you're already doing in the code you commented, or you can switch to SOSL. SOSL [does use the asterisk as a wild card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm):

> FIND {Joe Sm*}
> FIND {Joe Sm?th*}

but bear in mind that the semantics of a SOSL search are quite different from SOQL - you're searching across records, not specific field values.